# How do I store the values in best java collection structure

Tags: java, collections

What type of collection structure would be best suited for below structure .
I want to create a rows of start and end positions and wanted to store it as a structure. based on the number of occurrences I want to execute a function .

Example

```
StartPosition Endposition 
1                5
6                9
10               14
15               18
```

Now I want to store the the values like ( (1,5) , (6,9) , (10,14) , (15,18) ) 
Now I want to execute a function 4 times as I have 4 occurrences

```
for (i=1 , i <4 , i ++)
{
f(xyz , Startposition , endposition)
}
```

Comment: Apart from executing a function for all ranges, should this data structure support other operations? What about searches, queries, insertions, check if one range fits into another one, etc? Please clarify this, as it's essential when deciding the right data structure. Also provide the expected time complexity for each operation, i.e. insertion should be `O(1)` i.e. constant time, lookups also `O(1)`, removals `O(n)`, etc

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use create a simple class and a List<> of this class.

```
public class Range{

private int start;
private int end;

// constructor
// gets and setts
}
```

And you would use like this:

```
List<Range> ranges = new ArrayList<>();
ranges.add(new Range(1,5));
ranges.add(new Range(6,9));
...
ranges.add(new Range(x,y));


for(Range range : ranges){
    f(xyz, range.getStart(), range.getEnd());
}
```

Comment: Why do you need two `for` loops here?

Comment: you don't.. my bad. I edited and it should be better now.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, two dimensional array would do.   Do you have any reason why you want a collection here?

Comment: Actually `array` is also a `collection` (**P.S.** I do not mean it relates to `java.utils.Collection`)

Answer (score -1):

**Option 1:** use `Array`. This is very simple.

```
int[] arr = { 1, 5, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 18 };

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    int start = arr[i];
    int end = arr[i + 1];
    // payload
}
```

**Option 2:** use `TreeSet` with custom comparator. A little bit more difficult, but code is more clear.

```
Set<Pair<Integer, Integer>> ranges = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt((ToIntFunction<Pair<Integer, Integer>>)Pair::getKey).thenComparingInt(Pair::getValue));
ranges.add(new Pair<>(1, 5));
ranges.add(new Pair<>(6, 9));
ranges.add(new Pair<>(10, 14));
ranges.add(new Pair<>(15, 18));

for (Pair<Integer, Integer> range : ranges) {
    int start = range.getKey();
    int end = range.getValue();
    // payload
}
```

Comment: Never use arrays, unless for some homework for which the professor has asked specifically to use arrays, or unless you're dealing with very tight constraints for memory and time, i.e. complex stuff such as machine learning or genetic algorithms, etc. (Btw I haven't downvoted)

Comment: I do not care for downvote. Actually I do not agree. I prefer using arrays, especially when I know target size. In current example, I use `int`, and do not have to convert it to `Integer`, when using `Map`. So, I use arrays very often, thinking what I am doing.

Comment: OK, it's totally debatable, I think, just a matter of taste. My point is that arrays are low-level, you have the elements and you're done, while collections allow for lookups, sorting, are resizable, etc. I agree in that arrays and primitives are the way to go if you can't afford wrapper types.

Comment: I agree with your notes as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can use built in `java.awt.Point` class to set X,Y values. Stores those objects in either `java.util.ArrayList` or `java.util.LinkedList`

Comment: Actually both `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.LinkedList` are ordered!